# Signal Continuation

Tags: dft

Given the first half second of a signal, generate the remainder of the signal, assuming the conditions that used to generate the signal remain constant.

There are no changes on how the signal is being generated. For the case of piano, the key remained pressed down (because once the key is released the waveform that that note quickly dampen to zero), in which the signal will slowly dampen to zero.

[image: The sound of three piano keys pressed together.]

Have anyone tried doing this?

One way we might go about doing this is to use DFT, get the spectrum and sort of extend it. The other way is to fit in some probabilistic (multivariate normal for example) model and sample from there. In both cases, whatever that is generated needs to fit well with the first half-second of the sound.

Moreover, I wonder how long of the signal do we need to generate the next block of signal. Is the section 2.45s to 2.50s enough?

Comment: `One way we might go about doing this is to use DFT, get the spectrum and sort of extend it.` Wouldn't this be equivalent to just copying the first half to the second half?

Comment: The sound is made up of a few piano keys. As the ratio of intervals is irrational, there is no LCM of the period (unless you make some sort of approximation).
Merely copying from the first half to the second half will result in a break of the periodicity at the joint, which can be detectable.

Comment: I mean, that's nice and all, but isn't this question a bit too broad? There's infinitely many ways to come up with an continuation, and you're not given us *any* target function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume the chord is stationary, you can model the spectrum (overtones, etc.) of each pitched component after the break as roughly the same as before the break.  If you assume the spectrum is composed of a stationary and sparse set nearly periodic waveforms, then you can use phase vocoder analysis methods across a few overlapped FFT windows from just before the break to estimate the phase and rate of change of phase of each pitch component at and across the break.  If you assume the variation from stationarity is an ADSR envelope, then you can use a set of spectral peak magnitudes from successive windows of your signal to estimate the decay rate of each spectral component's amplitude.

Then, given the estimated frequency, phase estimate measured at the break, and amplitude envelope estimate from the ADSR's 1st derivative, of a sparse pile of sinusoids, you can try extending each sinusoidal component forward from the break by synthesizing a set of decaying sinusoids.

You might want to extend the spectrum starting from slightly before the break (by 1 or 2 overlapped FFT windows) and cross fade the synthesized extension with the existing waveform to reduce any discontinuities due to estimation errors.

This may or may not be a sufficiently close model of  your pitch generating musical sources, and thus, how they will continue to generate sound.

If you want to attempt even more detailed modeling, you might examine across the overlapped windows for the existence of tremolo or vibrato, and add those estimates to the synthesizer.

If there seems to be a noise floor (stuff that doesn't fit sinusoidal modeling in the phase vocoder analysis) below the estimated spectrum peaks, you might also add that amount of colored noise to the resulting extension.